# How can I assign a const unsigned char value to a variable inside a condition in c++?

Tags: c++, arduino, esp32

I am using C++ for programming a microcontroller, and I have this situation.

I have several `const unsigned char` in a `.h` file. Ex:

```
const unsigned char epd_bitmap_icon1 [] = {...
const unsigned char epd_bitmap_icon2 [] = {...
```

I have a function that takes one of this variables:

```
void drawBitmap(int16_t x, int16_t y, uint8_t *bitmap, int16_t w, int16_t h, uint16_t color);
```

In this case, I need to conditionally pass a different bitmap based on a certain value.

In python would be something like this:

```py
if value > 80:
    icon = epd_bitmap_icon1
elif value > 30:
    icon = epd_bitmap_icon2
else:
    icon = edp_bitmap_icon3
```

and later pass the `icon` value to `drawBitmap` as the third argument.

I don't know how to do it in C++, I have tried this:

```
    if (batteryChargePercent > 80) {
        unsigned char* icon = epd_bitmap_icon1;
    }
    else if (batteryChargePercent > 30) {
        unsigned char* icon = epd_bitmap_icon2;

    } else {
        unsigned char* icon = epd_bitmap_icon3;
    }
```

But I get this error:

```
error: invalid conversion from 'const unsigned char*' to 'unsigned char*' [-fpermissive]
```

Comment: You have *two* problems, but only one is mentioned in the error message you show. The arrays are *constant* arrays of bytes, while `icon` is a pointer to *non*-constant bytes.

Comment: If you're sure what you're doing, you could use a `const_cast<unsigned char*>(...)`. But why do you need a non const pointer there at all??

Comment: If your `drawBitmap` function doesn't modify the array pointed to by `bitmap` then you should change the type of that parameter from `uint8_t*` to `const uint8_t*` to resolve your compiler error.

Comment: `{ unsigned char* icon = epd_bitmap_icon1; }` obviously doesn't work because `icon` here is a local variable and its scope ends at `}` so at the end of the `if` block there's no `icon` anymore

Comment: Make the function to accept `const uint8_t*` instead of `uint8_t*` (if it's not supposed to modify it) or copy the array into a non-const one first. The compiler stated the error pretty explicitly: dropping the const compromises type safety.

Comment: @EricPostpischil sorry you are right, I just removed it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declare the variable once outside the `if`, and assign it in the `if`.

```
const unsigned char *icon;
if (batteryChargePercent > 80) {
    icon = epd_bitmap_icon1;
} else if (batteryChargePercent > 30) {
    icon = epd_bitmap_icon2;
} else {
    icon = epd_bitmap_icon3;
}
```

You need to use `const` in the pointer declaration to solve the error message.

Comment: Sorry, left out the `const`

Comment: Problem here, the pointer itself cannot be const (i.e., you cannot declare e.g. an `int const` this way).

Comment: The pointer isn't const, the data it points to is const. To declare a constant pointer it would be `unsigned char *const icon`

Comment: yes, I understand that in this specific case, the ptr is non-const; the reason I wrote is, this cannot be generalized to all cases.

Comment: But those cases don't require const consistency in the assignment, so there's no type checking error.

Answer (score 2):

You can either use a ternary, for simple cases:

```
const unsigned char* icon = batteryChargePercent > 80 ? epd_bitmap_icon1 :
                      batteryChargePercent > 30 ? epd_bitmap_icon2 :
                                                  epd_bitmap_icon3;
```

or, if it's more complicated, you might use a lambda that's called on-the-spot:

```
const unsigned char* icon = [&]() {
    if (batteryChargePercent > 80) {
        return epd_bitmap_icon1;
    }
    else if (batteryChargePercent > 30) {
        return epd_bitmap_icon2;
    } else {
        return epd_bitmap_icon3;
    }
}();
```

Also, while not yet standard, statement expressions might help you:

```
const unsigned char* icon = ({
    const unsigned char* retval;
    if (batteryChargePercent > 80) {
        retval = epd_bitmap_icon1;
    }
    else if (batteryChargePercent > 30) {
        retval = epd_bitmap_icon2;
    } else {
        retval = epd_bitmap_icon3;
    }
    retval;
});
```

Comment: The error message says he's assigning a pointer to `const` to a pointer to non `const`.

Comment: @paolo Added the const. Also adding a third solution.